# Github PR not reflecting the code in the branches

Tags: git, github

I branched one feature branch off of another. I changed code in one file and then made a PR where the second branch will merge into the first. That PR shows changes in 7 files. I have no idea why this is happening. If I do a git diff locally, it shows only the changes in one file. When I look at the branch on github, the PR is not reflecting what is actually in the code.

So, in summary :

- I took the initial branch of feature/branch1
- I branched off of it to create the second feature/branch2
- I then changed 1 file
- I then created a PR where branch 2 gets merged into branch1
- For some reason, the PR shows changes to 7 files
- A git diff on branch1 and branch2 shows only the changes in 1 file

Why is this happening and how do I correct it?

Comment: What is the target branch? Are the remote and local branch in sync? Which branches are you comparing locally (and how)?

Comment: If the remote and local branches are not in sync, I can't understand why? I did a push, I looked at the code and it appears to match, and attempting to repush tells me everything is up to date. Is there some way to check this?

Comment: What commit is shown in GitHub? What commit do you see locally with `git rev-parse your-branch`?

Comment: They are the same. The code on gihub is the same as my local code. For some reason, this isn't reflected in the PR

Comment: Does the PR include the commits? Is the source branch correct? What is the target branch? The PR shows the diff between "source branch" and "target branch"

Comment: Yes. The PRs include the commits. The code in the branches is up to date. For some reason, github is bringing the wrong code into the PR

Comment: I'm not following. If everything is included, what's the problem? Have you executed `git diff target...source` locally?

Comment: Yes. Doing this locally results in the single diff. Looking at the code on github reflects the proper changes. However, the PR is simply wrong

Comment: You are not providing the necessary details. What is the _target branch_ of your PR? Which files are changed in branch1? Why do you say "the code reflects the proper changes" but "the PR is incorrect"?